# Show that the limit of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, with $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1}=\frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}$ is a solution to $x^2+x-1=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, with $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1}=\frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}$is monotonically decreasing and bounded and that its limit is a solution to $x^2+x-1=0$

I proved by induction that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded between 0 and 1, but was unable to show that it is monotonically decreasing. Can anybody help me on that?

If I were able to show it is monotonically decreasing, I thought that I might be able to show that since $a_{n+1} = \frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n} \leq a_n \Rightarrow 0 \leq a_n^2 + a_n - 1$ and so it seems reasonable, since $a_n$ is decreasing, that $a_n^2 + a_n - 1$ approaches 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Does anybody have some hints on how to show that  $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is monotonically decreasing?

Comment: Are you sure that $a_n=\frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}$ and that on the rhs do not appear other thing than $n$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici rhs or lfh?

Comment: The same and only $n$ appears in both sides.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici His third paragraph leads me to believe that he intended $a_{n+1} = \frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}$.

Comment: @DavidH. You are right ! Thanks.

Comment: Yes I'm very sorry, it's supposed to be $a_{n+1} = \frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}$

Comment: Thanks ! It makes more sense. I must confess that I was just focusing on the title and did not see what was in the third paragraph as pointed by David H. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have concluded, we are required to show that $a_n^2 + a_n - 1 > 0$ which is same as showing that $a_n > \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the positive root of $x^2 + x -1$.

But this follows by induction as $1^2 + 1 - 1 > 0$ and if $a_n > \alpha$ then 
 $$a_{n+1} = \frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n} > \frac{1+\alpha}{2+\alpha} = \alpha $$

What happens as we vary $a_1$ across the real line?

Answer (score 0):

1. Prove that the function $x \mapsto \frac{1+x}{2+x}$ is increasing on $[0;1]$
2. Prove that $a_1 \ge a_2$

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could also use the fact that $$a_{n+1} = \frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}=1-\frac{1}{2+a_n}$$